# Show numbers per step count

Tags: javascript, comparative-review

I have a problem where I need to display the below output

```
1
23
456
78910
```

My first solution is

```
let numberStepper = (stepLimit) => {
  let stepCounter = 0;
  let step = '';

  for(let row = 1; row <= stepLimit; row++) {
      step = '';
      
     for(let col = 1; col <= row; col++) {
         stepCounter++;
         
         step += `${stepCounter}`  
     }

      if(stepCounter > stepLimit) {
          break;
      }

      console.log(step);
  }
   
}

numberStepper(10) // Gives desired output
```

Another solution that limits the number of steps output is below.

```
let numberStepper = (stepsLimit) => {
  let stepCounter = 0;
  let step = '';

  for(let row = 1; row <= stepsLimit; row++) {
      step = '';
      
     for(let col = 1; col <= row; col++) {
         stepCounter++;
         
         step += `${stepCounter}`  
     }

      console.log(step);
  }
   
}

numberStepper(4) // Gives desired output
```

How can I refactor this function to have a clean implementation?

Any ideas on the first implementation? where the argument determines the numbers displayed in the steps instead of using the number of steps as the determinant of the numbers displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### functions should return a value

It's unprofessional to use `console.log` for the output of a function. It's better to think of functions as a blackbox where you give it an input and it spits back an output.

If you were to write unit tests for your function, you would have to go out of your way to either mock `console.log` to see if it's used properly or to read directly from stdout. Those aren't the easiest options.

### give meaningful variable and function names

It's not intuitively easy to understand what the variable names are intended to represent.

For example, `step` should probably be renamed to `row` or `numbersOnRow` or even `rowString`.

---

Here is an alternative way that reduces the complexity. It follows the pattern that the length of each row increases by one consecutively. So in the end, no real need to have a double for loop. You can simply populate a list with all the values, and then loop through it once to build your output.

```js
const numberStepper = (stepLimit) => {
  // build list with prefilled values
  const list = (new Array(stepLimit))
    .fill(undefined)
    .map((_,i) => i + 1);
    
  const result = [];
  for(let i = 0, j = 1; i < list.length; i+=j, j++) {
    result.push(list.slice(i, i+j));
  }
  
  // format
  return result.map(row => row.join('')).join('\n');
}

const result = numberStepper(10);

console.log(result);
```